# Shopify api - uninstall app programmatically

Tags: shopify

I want to give the merchant the option to unlink their account from my app. Is there a way to issue a remove/ unlink request via shopify api?

Comment: They already have an uninstall your App link in their shop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge, the Shopify API doesn't provide a way for applications to uninstall themselves.

The Shopify admin interface already provides a way merchants to uninstall applications in a uniform manner.  You could link to this url where the merchant can remove the application.

`https://#{shop_name}.myshopify.com/admin/applications`

Or to link directly to your application, get your application's id by visiting your application in the partners interface, which has the format `https://app.shopify.com/services/partners/api_clients/#{application_id}`.  Then you can use a fragment to autoscroll the merchant to your application on the application's page:

`https://#{shop_name}.myshopify.com/admin/applications#application-#{application_id}`

Comment: guess this seems to be the only way at the moment. Thx

Answer (score 4):

This feature has just been added:
http://docs.shopify.com/api/authentication/uninstalling-applications

Comment: Do you u know if this works in cases where the merchant hasn't paid for their Shopify plan? -- other endpoints generally 404 but it would seem useful for this to continue to work...